# JScrollPane Viewport bigger than Frame

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I try to make a JFrame with a dynamical layout which should look like this

```
------------------------------------------| 
|                | Details                |
|                |                        |
|                |                        |
| list           |                        |
|                |                        |
|                |                        |
|                |     save               |
-------------------------------------------
```

Where list is some tree structure where when I chose some element, the details of the element appear in Details. Now the Details consist of multiple `JPanels` which I put into a `JPanel` with `BoxLayout`. Below this `JPanel` I have a save button.

Since there are a lot of details I put the `JPanel` Details into a `JScrollPane` however, this scrollPane ignores its purpos and the result is that the Details panel is bigger than the window size. This is it goes till the bottom hiding the save button and the rest of it is not visible. The scrollbar never appears.

I don't know if it has todo with the fact that when an element is selected I update the `JPanel`'s inside the `JScrollPane` or whatever.

Here is how I instantiate everything. First inside the right panel I add all `JPanel`'s in `firstPanel` and I put a button inside the `JPanel` bottom. Then

```
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    scrollPane=new JScrollPane(firstPanel);
    JPanel conScroll = new JPanel(new GridLayout());
    conScroll.add(scrollPane);
    add(conScroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

On the `JFrame` level I instantiate the left and right side however I only put the left hand side and an empty `JPanel` for the right side called `display`.

When I select an element I update all elements inside `firstPanel` I call `revalidate()` and `repaint()` on the right side panel. Then on the Frame level I remove all elements of `displayer` and then add the right side to `displayer`.

As suggested I made a minimal working example (updated).

So for this minimal example I removed the left side. What is left is a JFrame `EmpireEditor` with a display JPanel inside, inside which I then put a `unitEditor`. Uniteditor contains two JPanel one in the center and one south. The panel in the center is in a JScrollPane.

```
package main;

import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;



public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // Set System L&F
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
                    UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // handle exception
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // handle exception
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        EmpireEditor r = new EmpireEditor();
    }
}
```

The EmpireEditor

```
    package main;

import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class EmpireEditor extends JFrame {

    private JPanel display;
    private UnitEditor unitEditor;

    public EmpireEditor() {
        super("Editor");
        display = new JPanel();
        unitEditor = new UnitEditor();
        add(display);
        display.add(unitEditor);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

and here the UnitEditor a center Pannel where I just fill with a `PanelNumber` but  that's just so that there is something inside and that we can see that the scrollbars don't appear. The Idea is that the bottom is always there and the rest should be filled with the `JScrollPane`.

```
package main;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class UnitEditor extends JPanel {



    private PanelNumbers numbers = new PanelNumbers();

    private JScrollPane scrollPane;

    public UnitEditor() {
        super();

        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(firstPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        firstPanel.add(numbers);

        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        JButton save = new JButton("save");

        bottom.add(save);

        scrollPane=new JScrollPane(firstPanel);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottom,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

finally the `PanelNumber` but one could exchange this with anything.

```
package main;

import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class PanelNumbers extends JPanel{

    private Map<Value, JFormattedTextField> nums = new HashMap<>();



    public PanelNumbers(){
        super();

        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JFormattedTextField tmp;
        JPanel numbers;
        numbers = new JPanel();
        numbers.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Numbers"));
        numbers.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 6));
        for (Value s : Value.values()) {
            numbers.add(new JLabel(s.n()));
            tmp = new JFormattedTextField(NumberFormat.getInstance());
            setFocus(tmp);
            numbers.add(tmp);
            nums.put(s, tmp);
        }
        add(numbers);
    }

    public void setUnit(String name){
        for (Value key : nums.keySet())
            nums.get(key).setValue(0);
    }

    public void save(){

    }

    private int toNumber(String t) {
        int res = 0;
        try {
            res = Integer.parseInt(t);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return res;
    }

    private void setFocus(final JFormattedTextField num) {
        num.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        num.selectAll();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        //num.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20, 10));
        num.setMaximumSize(num.getPreferredSize());
    }

    public enum Value {
        // Kampf
        GROESSE("Groesse"),
        WAFFENFERTIGKEIT("Waffenfertigkeit"),
        FERNKAMPFFERTIGKEIT("Fernkampffertigkeit"),
        ANGRIFFSBONUS("Angriffs Bonus"),
        NAHKAMPFPANZERUNG("Panzerung nah"),
        FERNKAMPFPANZERUNG("Panzerung fern"),
        INITIATIVE("Initiative"),
        TP("Treffer"),
        // Mouvement
        FELDER("Felder"),
        BWS("Bewegungspunkte"),
        B("B Befehl"),
        A("A Befehl"),
        P("P Befehl"),
        H("H Befehl"),
        M("Manoever"),
        UEBERR("Ueberrenen"),
        //Moral
        FURCHTFAKTOR("Furchtfaktor"),
        MORALERST("Erster Moralwert"),
        MORALZWEIT("Zweiter Moralwert"),
        //Rest
        MAGIE("Magie"),
        KONTROL("Kontrollbereich"),
        STERNE("Sterne"),
        ELEMENTE("Elemente"),
        ELEMENTEPROFELD("Elemente pro Feld"),
        KOSTEN("Kosten");

        private String name;
        Value(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String n(){
            return name;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Please strongly consider creating and posting a valid [mcve]. Otherwise you will be making it very hard for us to fully understand your problem or help fix it.

Comment: `Now the Details consist of multiple JPanels` - you should be using a [Box Layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) on the details panels to allow you to easily swap panels based on the selection.

Comment: those panels stay the same I only add dynamically the right side at once. Late I will swap this with another one. I'm working on a minimal example but I need to install eclipse since I did this on AndroidStudio and I'm getting crazy trying to make a java Project again, no idea how I managed to do it the first time

Comment: Appreciate the effort, but your code is hardly minimal as it has way too much code completely unrelated to the problem at hand, and I have no idea what it's doing right or wrong.

Comment: setting the layout of `display` to `GridLayout(1,1)` solved the problem, somehow the original layout just let the inner panel become as big as it wants and hence the `JScrollPane` didn't feel the urge to make it self smaller and have scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setting the layout of `display` to `GridLayout(1,1)` solved the problem, somehow the original layout just let the inner panel become as big as it wants and hence the `JScrollPane` didn't feel the urge to make it self smaller and have scrollbars.